# R: why is "identical(c(1:3), c(1, 2, 3))" false?

Tags: r, integer, double

Why is `identical(c(1:3), c(1, 2, 3))` false? In other words, why is the former an integer while the latter is a double?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
R> class(1:3)
[1] "integer"
R> class(c(1,2,3))
[1] "numeric"
R>
```

In a nutshell, `:` as the sequence operator returns integer "because that is what folks really want".

Hence:

```
R> identical(1:3, c(1L,2L,3L))
[1] TRUE
R> identical(1*(1:3), c(1,2,3))
[1] TRUE
R>
```

Answer (score 5):

It has to do with the colon operator. From `?':'` or `help(':')`:

#### Details

> The binary operator : has two meanings: for factors a:b is equivalent to interaction(a, b) (but the levels are ordered and labelled differently).
>
> For other arguments from:to is equivalent to seq(from, to), and generates a sequence from from to to in steps of 1 or -1. Value to will be included if it differs from from by an integer up to a numeric fuzz of about 1e-7. Non-numeric arguments are coerced internally (hence without dispatching methods) to numeric—complex values will have their imaginary parts discarded with a warning.

#### Value

> For numeric arguments, a numeric vector. This will be of type integer if from is integer-valued and the result is representable in the R integer type, otherwise of type "double" (aka mode "numeric").

Comment: Also, from the help of `seq()`:
"seq.int and the default method of seq for numeric arguments return a vector of type "integer" or "double": programmers should not rely on which."

In other words, it is an arbitrary choice.

You can explicitly define integers by appending an "L" to an integer: `identical(1:3, c(1L, 2L, 3L))`